# how to make my program check if its a palindrome by ignoring non-alpha characters and white spaces

Tags: java

Hi this code currently checks if it is a palindrome if there all the letters are same capitalization and if there is no spaces. I am trying to make it so it ignores non-alpha and white spaces.

```
import java.util.*;

public class PalindromeTester
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      String original, reverse = "";
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter a string to check if it is a palindrome");
      original = in.nextLine();

      int length = original.length();

      for ( int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
         reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);

      if (original.equals(reverse))
         System.out.println("Entered string is a palindrome.");
      else
         System.out.println("Entered string is not a palindrome.");

   }
}
```

Comment: There's no code in there that attempts to ignore non-alpha and white spaces.  We're not going to write your code for you.  Please make an attempt, and then if you have trouble, you can post the code you've tried and ask about that.

Comment: `original = original.replaceAll("\\P{L}+", "")`

Comment: sorry i should of said i have no idea of how to add it and any help would be appreciated maybe a link to somewhere that shows it

Comment: also the other guy scv.stackkk answered it by adding one line of code thats proper help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you set your variable "`original`" to the next line of text, you can call the `replaceAll()` string method to strip away any unwanted characters with a specifier parameter. Also, you can call `toLowerCase()` to get all lower case strings.

```
  String original, reverse = "";
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter a string to check if it is a palindrome");
  original = in.nextLine();
  original = original.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]","").toLowerCase();
```

`replaceAll()` uses a regular expression to search for the specified text and replaces it with the second parameter value.

Here's a quick example for the palindrome "racecar":

```
    String original = "rA89293cEC@Ar";
    original = original.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]","").toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(original);
```

Comment: wow thank you so much i couldnt find how to include that your a life saver

Answer (score 0):

Can also be done without replacing Chars (and copying the String):

```
  public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {

        int start = 0;
        int end = s.length()-1;
        while(!s.isEmpty() && Character.isSpaceChar(start))
        {
            start++;
        }
        if ( s.isEmpty())
            return true;

        while (start < end )
        {
            while( ( start < end) && !Character.isLetterOrDigit(s.charAt(start)))
            {
                start++;
            }
             while( ( start < end) &&  !Character.isLetterOrDigit(s.charAt(end))) 
            {
                end--;
            }
            if ( start >= end )
                return true;
            if ( Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(start)) != Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(end)))
                return false;
            start++;end--;
        }

        return true;
    }
```